# Set a integer value to indexpath.row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make quiz program. When user click the right answer, the program is working correctly, but if user click the wrong answer, program have to show the right answer, program knows which cell is correct but it can't call the method.

Here is my project's part;

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CGRect rect = cell.frame;
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIImageView *back = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListGray"] ];

databaseNameUser = SQL;
NSArray *documentPathsUser = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirUser = [documentPathsUser objectAtIndex:0];
databasePathUser = [documentsDirUser stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseNameUser];
sqlLocal= [[Sqlite alloc]initWithFile:databasePathUser];


NSString *query1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT AnswerID from tblAnswer where QuestionID = %i",[[questionsID objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
answerInfo=[sqlLocal executeQuery:query1];
NSMutableArray *answerIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSMutableDictionary *d in answerInfo) {

    [answerIDArray addObject:[d valueForKey:@"AnswerID"]];

}


NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT answerID from tblDogruCevaplar where QuestionID = %i",[[questionsID objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
NSArray *answerInfo2=[sqlLocal executeQuery:query2];
//NSMutableArray *answerDogru = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSMutableDictionary *d in answerInfo2) {

    answerDogruDefault=[d valueForKey:@"answerID"];

}


for (int indexOfArray = 0; indexOfArray<4; indexOfArray++ ){



    if ([answerDogruDefault intValue] == [[answerIDArray objectAtIndex:indexOfArray] intValue]){

        //NSLog(@"indexpath = %i",indexOfArray);

        indexPathInt = indexOfArray;

    }
}



BOOL selx;
if (answerType==2)
    selx = [self isSelected:indexPath];
else
    selx = [lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath];

if (selx) {
    back = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecildiYesilTikli2.png"] ];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [view addSubview:back];
    cell.backgroundView =  view;


    if ([self isAnswerCorrect]) {

        if (indexPathInt == indexPath.row) {

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.f target:self selector:@selector(dogruCevapSignal:) userInfo:cell repeats:NO];
        }

    }else{

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        NSIndexPath *a = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathInt inSection:0];

        NSLog(@"a = %i",a.row);

        cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathInt inSection:0]];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.f target:self selector:@selector(dogruCevapSignal:) userInfo:cell repeats:NO];

    }

    back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 12,rect.size.width,rect.size.height-12);
} else {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    if (lastIndexPath != nil){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [view addSubview:back];
        cell.backgroundView =  view;

        back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 12,rect.size.width,rect.size.height-12);
        back = nil;
    }
}
[view addSubview:back];
cell.backgroundView =  view;

back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 12,rect.size.width,rect.size.height-12);

}

-(void)dogruCevapSignal:(NSTimer *)cell{

UITableViewCell *defaultCell=(UITableViewCell *)[cell userInfo];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
    defaultCell.alpha = 0;
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    defaultCell.hidden = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        defaultCell.alpha = 1;
    } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        defaultCell.hidden = NO;
        defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }];

}];
}
```

i cant call this method in wrong answer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.f target:self selector:@selector(dogruCevapSignal:) userInfo:cell repeats:NO];
```

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what your question is. Try being more specific on where you need help.

Comment: For example in my question i have 4 answers, when the user click the wrong answer, i want to show right answer to user, so i want to like flashing the right answer cell, but as you can see on above method is not calling. Sorry dont have good english, i hope you can understand what i want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSIndexPath.row` is read-only, so you need to make a new `NSIndexPath` object from an existing one, like this:

```
NSIndexPath *original = ...
int newRow = ...;
NSIndexPath *changedRow = [NSIndexPath
    indexPathForRow:newRow              // Use the new row
          inSection:original.section];  // Use the original section
```

Comment: i tried that, but i got same error, if the user click second cell which indexpath.row = 1 , i want to reach to my first cell with using indexpath.  cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathInt inSection:indexPath.row]]; and i write this NSLog(@"cellString = %@",cell.textLabel.text); but cell text is coming 'null'.

Comment: @TwentyThr23 It's supposed to be `cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathInt inSection:indexPath.section]]` (section, not row at the end).

Comment: Ok i found solution, you are right and thank you very much your interest, the problem was about my wrong algorithm. But i fixed it, Thanks again.