# Reset indexPath for uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I have a collection view which looks like

[image]

1st cell will hold some text , and from 2nd cell onwards data is populated from a data manager

To handle this i have code something like this

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if(indexPath.row==0){

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(customCellNibName, forIndexPath: indexPath) 

            let offer: TGOfferDataSource? = dataSource?.dataforIndexPath(indexPath) as? TGOfferDataSource
            cell.setOfferData(offer!)

            return cell
        }
        else if(indexPath.row != 0)
        {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellNibName, forIndexPath: indexPath) 

            let product: TGProductDataSource? = dataSource?.dataforIndexPath(indexPath) as? TGProductDataSource
            cell.setProductData(product!)

            return cell
        }
}
```

The issue is 1st product from data manager is hidden behind this grey cell.

So i figure i will have to increment index path in elseif part. Something like indexPath in elseif part should also starts from 0.
(Swift and cells are xib)

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524943/set-a-integer-value-to-indexpath-row) but how to do this in swift

EDIT
If I remove if part , it looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you add your dataSource `dataforIndexPath`method ? Also, why is your product class called `TGProductDataSource`?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo dataforIndexPath just returns value of data at indexPath.item, pretty obvious, and TG is just our enterprise naming convention.Thanks for helping, anyways the answer below did the trick

Comment: I was trying to know whether you need an indexpath as parameter or if just an index was sufficient, since it looks like you are not using the section property of NSIndexPath.

Comment: my bad , from next time vl try to post complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new `NSIndexPath` in swift using following

```
let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
```

And you can pass above `path` to your `dataforIndexPath` in the else part. Hope that helps!